# Function::apply when BiFunction<T, U, R> is required

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

I am confused about the following line:

```java
Seq<String> s1 = seq.zip(split, Function::apply);
```

In this snippet:

```
static String underscoreToCamel(String str) {
        UnaryOperator<String> capitalize = s -> s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        
        Seq<UnaryOperator<String>> seq = c -> {
            c.accept(String::toLowerCase);
            while (true) {
                c.accept(capitalize);
            }
        };
        List<String> split = Arrays.asList(str.split("_"));
        Seq<String> s1 = seq.zip(split, Function::apply);
        String a = s1.join("");
        return a;
    }

public interface Seq<T> {
        void consume(Consumer<T> consumer);

        static <T> Seq<T> unit(T t) {
            return consumer -> consumer.accept(t);
        }

        default <E> Seq<E> map(Function<T, E> function) {
            return consumer -> consume(t -> consumer.accept(function.apply(t)));
        }

        default <E> Seq<E> flatMap(Function<T, Seq<E>> function) {
            return consumer -> consume(t -> function.apply(t).consume(consumer));
        }


        default String join(String sep) {
            StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(sep);
            consume(t -> joiner.add(t.toString()));
            return joiner.toString();
        }

        static <T> T stop() {
            throw StopException.INSTANCE;
        }

        default void consumeTillStop(Consumer<T> consumer) {
            try {
                consume(consumer);
            } catch (StopException ignore) {}
        }

        default <U, R> Seq<R> zip(Iterable<U> iterable, BiFunction<T, U, R> function) {
            return c -> {
                Iterator<U> iterator = iterable.iterator();
                consumeTillStop(t -> {
                    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        c.accept(function.apply(t, iterator.next()));
                    } else {
                        stop();
                    }
                });
            };
        }

    }
```

I do understand that `Function::apply` is a **method reference** and that the method wants a `BiFunction<T, U, R>`. But I do not get how this is compatible.

What exactly does it resolve to? Why can I supply `Function::apply` in this case?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-

Comment: `Function.apply()` is non-`static` 1-parameter method, so it needs an instance to run; but `Function::apply` is not providing such instance, so needs an additional argument when called, meaning it is equivalent to a 2-parameter function (first argument will be `this`) || `BiFunction<T, U, R> function = Function::apply` ~= `(T t, U u) -> t.apply(u)` returning type `R` ( if I am correct, in this specific case: `(Consumer<String> t, String u) -> t.apply(s)` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Non-static method reference

This is indeed an interesting one, as it uses one of the *special rules* that method references allow for.

Quick example, suppose you demand a `Function<String, Integer>`, then one could write `String::length`, eventhough this method has a different signature. The requested signature is:

```java
Integer apply(String x) { ... }
```

but we supplied a method that only has `int length()`, so no `String` argument at all. However, that method is non-static and operates on instances of `String`. So Java can assume you meant to call that method on that instance, and by that deduce the first parameter to the method. I.e. `s -> s.length()`.

---

### Generic details

The same is happening in your setup. First of all, you have to understand what the generics for your requested `BiFunction<T, U, R>` resolve to. They are:

- `T`: `UnaryOperator<String>`
- `U`: `String`
- `R`: `Consumer<T>`, so `Consumer<UnaryOperator<String>>`

Quite complex, but okay.

### Actual signature

Now, the requested signature is:

```java
Consumer<UnaryOperator<String>> apply(UnaryOperator<String> t, String u)
```

When you give your method reference `Function::apply`, whose signature is:

```java
R apply(T t)
```

so, in this case:

```java
Consumer<UnaryOperator<String>> apply(String u)
```

Then, the first argument from the required signature (`UnaryOperator<String> t`) is again deducted from the fact that `Function::apply` is a non-static method that operates on the `Function` instance, which happens to be compatible with `UnaryOperator<String>`, since `UnaryOperator extends Function`.

### Implementation

So `Function::apply` essentially is the same as implementing your `BiFunction` as:

```java
Consumer<UnaryOperator<String>> apply(UnaryOperator<String> t, String u) {
  return t.apply(u);
}
```

Taking the function from the first argument and applying it to the second, returning the result.

Comment: BTW the `length` method could have been declared `public int length(String this)` (only works inside the `String` class) - `this` acts as the first parameter of a non-static method (( reason for this: allow annotations on `this` ))

Answer (score 1):

`Function::apply` is a method reference that refers to the apply method of the Function interface in the line `Seq s1 = seq.zip(split, Function::apply)`. It serves as the second argument to the zip method, which requires a `BiFunction` functional interface and anticipates one that accepts two arguments of types `T` and `U` and returns a result of type `R`.

In this instance, `T` is an `UnaryOperator<String>` (from `Seq<UnaryOperator<String>> seq)`, `U` is a String (from `List<String> split`), and `R` is a String when the zip method is executed. Because `String::apply` has the same signature as the apply method of the Function interface, which accepts a single argument of type String and returns a String, it is used as a reference to the `Function::apply` method.

The seq sequence of functions will be applied to each element of the split list by the zip method as iterates over the split list's elements. The apply method of the Function interface will be used to apply each `UnaryOperator<String>` in seq to the corresponding String element in the split.